# Roots of $x^3-2=0$...

Tags: polynomials, roots-of-cubics

When I was solving this,$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned} x^3-2&=0\\x^3&=2\\x&=2^{1/3}\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$,I got $x=2^{1/3}$

But this is only one root...I know there are two complex roots also...But not getting how we are getting complex roots and what are they....?

Please explain me, I am not getting.....

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: the complex cube roots of one satisfy $r^2 + r + 1 = 0$

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$x^3=2$$
i.e$$x^3-(2^\frac{1}{3})^3=0$$
i.e. $$(x-2^\frac{1}{3})(x^2+2^\frac{1}{3}x+2^\frac{2}{3})=0$$
so, $$x=2^\frac{1}{3} \text{or}$$

$$x^2+2^\frac{1}{3}x+2^\frac{2}{3}=0$$

Solve this quadratic equation on your own, you'll get what you want!

Answer (score 2):

See $x^3=2$ is one solution but by solving the equation we get other two solutions like this. $$ x^3-2= (x)^3-(2^\frac{1}{3})^3=(x-2^\frac{1}{3})(x^2+2^\frac{1}{3}x+2^\frac{2}{3})$$.
Solving $x^2+2^\frac{1}{3}x+2^\frac{2}{3}$ you will get the other two solution which is complex because complex roots occur in conjugate and it is a quardratic equation as well.

Answer (score 2):

### Solving the Equation: $x^3 - 2 = 0$

**Given Equation:** $x^3 = 2$

This is a cubic equation, and we are looking for values of $x$ that satisfy the equation.

#### Factoring the Equation:

We can factor the equation using the difference of cubes formula: $a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$.
$$x^3 - 2 = (x - \sqrt[3]{2})(x^2 + x\sqrt[3]{2} + (\sqrt[3]{2})^2) = 0$$

#### Roots:

1. **Real Root:**
   $x = \sqrt[3]{2}$
2. **Complex Roots:**

For complex roots, we solve the quadratic equation obtained from factoring:

$$x^2 + x(\sqrt[3]{2}) + (\sqrt[3]{2})^2 = 0$$

Using the quadratic formula $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ we get,

$$x \in \bigg(\frac{-1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2^{2/3}}, \frac{-1 - i\sqrt{3}}{2^{2/3}}\bigg)$$

These are the complex roots of the equation $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could use some introduction to *roots of unity*.

For instance,  $3$rd roots of unity are anything whose cube is $1$.  It turns out that there are three of them. One of those is the familiar old number $1$.  Of course,  $$1^3=1.$$

The other two happen to not be real numbers. Turns out,  they're $$-1/ 2+\sqrt3/2i$$ and $$-1/ 2-\sqrt3/2i.$$

As to how we find them, there's arguably a few different ways.   But basically this gets you into the subject of **complex numbers**, as well as, rather obviously, complex analysis.

For starters,  and as a point of departure,  let's see Euler's formula (in full generality):

$$e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z.$$

This works out nicely in terms of power series and what not.   I'll leave it for you to explore these ideas a little more as you progress.

One last note: the $n$th roots of unity can always be written as powers of $$e^{2\pi i/n},$$ which is thus an example of a *primitive* root.